# "Activity Monitor Job" java.lang.NullPointerException in Eclipse 3.6

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I keep getting

"Activity Monitor Job".
java.lang.NullPointerException

while working with Eclipse 3.6

Has anybody experienced something similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two solutions were suggested on

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=343688#c10

1: Disable "Synchronize Automatically" in the view menu of the task list.

[image]

2: Close the Task List view so it is not visible on startup, and under Preferences > General > Startup and Shutdown disable **Mylyn Team UI** and **Mylyn Tasks UI**

The first solution was reported as working.